# mapping of coordinates to the resized image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, mapping, coordinates

I have original image of size (969,348) and the resized image is (696,484).
I have a point (385,400) in the resized image, so I want to plot it to the original image.
`oldx = 385 oldy = 400`
I have resized it using

```
resize(org, resizeimage, Size(org.rows / 0.5, org.cols / 2), 0, 0, INTER_AREA);
```

I am using OpenCV C++ and where I am confused with the rows and cols, what is the width and height.
I have tried this but it gives me (0,484) coordinate.

```
Point(round(float((oldx / org.cols)) * resizeimage.cols), round(float((oldy / org.rows))) * resizeimage.rows)
```

Comment: I think you need to know about how types of resize work https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html. and reverse them

Comment: I have edited the question and added my code.

Comment: try this `Point(round(float((1.0*oldx / org.cols)) * resizeimage.cols), round(float((1.0*oldy / org.rows))) * resizeimage.rows)` you cast `float` incorrectly

Comment: its giving the point out of the image , the new coordinates are (276,484) and image size is  (969,348)

Comment: it should be `Point((1.0*oldx * org.cols / resizeimage.cols), float(1.0*oldy * org.rows) / resizeimage.rows)` the formula is incorrect

Comment: integer division already causes one value to become 0... please learn about integer division. you should also work on a [mre]. from your code all the stuff could be removed that isn't exactly these literal numbers and the calculation.

Comment: Reading your question again, I realized you want to get the inverse direction (from resized to original). The fact that "the distance for the center is proportional to the scaling" is still valid. In case you want me to edit my answer, please respond.

Answer (score 1):

The distance for the center is proportional to the scaling (in each axis).

We may compute `newx` and `newy` as follows:

- Subtract `x_original_center` and `y_original_center` from `oldx` and `oldy`.
  After subtraction, (0, 0) is the "new center" (applies "centered coordinate system").
- Scale the "zero centered" coordinates by `scale_x` and `scale_y`.
- Convert the "scaled zero centered" coordinates to "top left (0, 0)" by adding `x_scaled_center` and `y_scaled_center`.

---

Illustration:

```
Origin:
(0,0)                     New coordinate system: (0,0) center 
     -----------------                       -----------------                
    |                 | x -= (cols-1)/2     |    (0,0)        |
    |                 | ===============>    |        +        |
    |                 | y -= (rows-1)/2     |                 |
     -----------------                       -----------------
     
     
    After scaling:
    The distance to the center is proportional to the scale.
    In x axis the distance is proportional to x_scale
    In y axis the distance is proportional to y_scale


                                        -------------
                                       |             |
                                       |      ^    o |
                                       | y*sy |      |
     --------^--------                 |      |      |
    |      y |     o  |    Scale       |      V      |
    |        +<--->   | ===========>   |      +<-->  |
    |           x     |                |       x*sx  |
     -----------------                 |             |
                                       |             |
                                       |             |
                                       |             |
                                        -------------    
                                        
Convert the scaled result to origin (0, 0): 
newx += (new_cols-1)/2
newy += (new_rows-1)/2
```

---

Computing the center accurately:
The C++ conversion is:
(0, 0) is the top left, and (cols-1, rows-1) is the bottom right coordinate.
The accurate center coordinate is:
`x_original_center = (original_rows-1.0)/2.0`
`y_original_center = (original_cols-1.0)/2.0`

---

C++ code sample:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

int main()
{
    double scale_x = 2.0;
    double scale_y = 0.5;

    int oldx = 385;
    int oldy = 400;

    cv::Mat org = cv::Mat::zeros(cv::Size(969, 348), CV_8UC1);  //Fill with zeros (for example).
    cv::Mat resizeimage;

    //Height and width before resize:
    int rows = org.rows;    //384
    int cols = org.cols;    //969

    //cv::resize(org, resizeimage, Size(org.rows / 0.5, org.cols / 2.0), 0, 0, INTER_AREA);

    //Instead of dividing by 0.5, sacle by 2.0 (and Instead of dividing by 2.0, scale by 0.5)
    cv::resize(org, resizeimage, cv::Size((int)std::round(rows * scale_x), (int)std::round(cols * scale_y)), 0, 0, cv::INTER_AREA);

    //Height and width after resize:
    int resized_rows = resizeimage.rows;    //485
    int resized_cols = resizeimage.cols;    //696

    //Center before resize:
    double x_original_center = ((double)cols - 1.0) / 2.0;  //484.0
    double y_original_center = ((double)rows - 1.0) / 2.0;  //173.5

    //Center after resize:
    double x_scaled_center = ((double)resized_cols - 1.0) / 2.0;    //347.5
    double y_scaled_center = ((double)resized_rows - 1.0) / 2.0;    //242

    //Subtract the center, scale, and add the "scaled center".
    int newx = (int)std::round((oldx - x_original_center) * scale_x + x_scaled_center); //150
    int newy = (int)std::round((oldy - y_original_center) * scale_y + y_scaled_center); //355

    std::cout << "newx = " << newx << std::endl << "newy = " << newy << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer map coordinates in the following way:

```
float x_ratio = resizeimage.cols / static_cast<float>(org.cols);
float y_ratio = resizeimage.rows / static_cast<float>(org.rows);
cv::Point newPoint(static_cast<int>(oldx * x_ratio), 
                   static_cast<int>(oldy * y_ratio));
```